# How to check if element exists in an array without for loop?

Tags: go

I'm doing a challenge in which I can't use `for` loops, so I'm implementing it using `goto` statements.

Basically I'm getting an array of positive numbers so negative numbers such as `-1` need to be eliminated. But by doing so length of my array shortens and thus, the next round that I check whether or not my loops is ended, I receive `index out of range`.

I'm looking for a way to determine if the next element exist, and if not, stop the program.

My code:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Please enter number of test cases: ")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    testCasesNumberInput := scanner.Text()
    testCaseNumber, _ := strconv.Atoi(testCasesNumberInput)
    if testCaseNumber <= 0 {
        fmt.Print("Number of test cases must be higher or equal to 1")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Please enter test cases: ")
    scanner.Scan()
    scannerText := scanner.Text()
    input := strings.Fields(scannerText)
    testCases := make([]int, len(input))
    if len(testCases) != testCaseNumber {
        fmt.Print("Wrong number of test cases!")
        return
    }

    inputIndex := 0
    outputIndex := 0
    var intInput int

start:
    if inputIndex < len(testCases) {
        intInput, _ = strconv.Atoi(input[inputIndex])
        testCases[inputIndex] = intInput

        inputIndex++
        goto start
    }

    goto prepareResult

prepareResult:
    if outputIndex > len(testCases) {
        fmt.Print("result: \n", testCases)
        return
    }
    if testCases[outputIndex] <= 0 {
        copy(testCases[outputIndex:], testCases[outputIndex+1:])
        testCases[len(testCases)-1] = 0
        testCases = testCases[:len(testCases)-1]
        if outputIndex == 0 {
            if len(testCases) < outputIndex+2 {
                fmt.Print("")
                return
            }
        } else {
            if len(testCases) < outputIndex {
                fmt.Print("")
                return
            }
        }
    }

    outputIndex++
    goto prepareResult
}
```

Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use recursion for your challenge instead?

Comment: Can you shorten testCases once, at the end of your loop, instead of at every iteration?

Comment: @gonutz I thought that the reason `for` loops were banned was to emphasize on golang abilities rather than standard ways.


@MarkPlotnick  Would you kindly provide more information about your idea?

Comment: Looks like a simple off-by-one error at a glance: `if outputIndex >= len(testCases) { return }`

Comment: @Peter the length is actually correct...if the length of testCases is 5 and we remove 2 elements from it and the outputIndex is three, the `outputIndex == len(testCases)` but there is no `testCase[outputIndex]`, so `index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is:

1. remove if and else statements which are checking `testCases[outputIndex] <= 0` and  replace it with a `goto` pointing at `prepareResult` which keeps your `outputIndex` at it's current value and since you've already deleted one element out of your array it'll work just fine.
2. change `if outputIndex > len(testCases)` to `if outputIndex >= len(testCases)` for good measures.